# Meaning of these wildcards/paths *~ .*~ \#*\#

Tags: wildcards, make, rm

In a `Makefile` I am studying I saw the following line:

```
@rm -f *~ .*~ \#*\#
```

Probably because these are special characters and hard to search, I can't find anything about the meaning of:

- `*~`
- `.*~`
- `\#*\#`

They do not appear to be defined in the GNU make manual, so I guess these are file path specifications I haven't run into yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t think there’s anything special going on here.

```
*~
```

Any files ending with tilde.

```
.*~
```

Any hidden files ending with tilde.

```
\#*\#
```

Any file which both begins and ends with the hash sign.

Without context one couldn’t say with certainty what the purpose of such files may be, but if I were to speculate I’d suggest they refer to temporary files created by an editor or compiler.

Comment: I was wondering if they were to be taken literally.  From the context I'm working in, I'm not sure where such files would come from but I guess the original author of the file must have run into them.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case my guess would be edging towards editor temporary files.

Comment: Files ending with tilde are temp files for emacs. The temp files with hashes are from vi.